# Setting SFR by single bits or as a byte on 8051 arch

Tags: assembly, 8051

Is there a difference in assigning a whole byte to an SFR or applying an AND or OR to it's value?

In other words, does it matter if I set some bits to same value as they were previously or this can trigger some hardware reaction?

For example I start from:

```
MOV UARTCON, 0x9b
```

Then with the same final value I can do

```
ORL UARTCON, 0x40
```

or

```
MOV UARTCON, 0xdb
```

or even

```
SETB UARTCON.6
```

Is there any difference?

I'm not talking particularly about UARTCON here, but about general mechanism of SFRs. Is the set of a bit matters or only the change of that bit?

**UPD** I can narrow the question: are bit addressable SFRs altered internally by bits or as a whole bytes even with instructions like `CLR`, `SETB`, `ORL` and `AND`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be some bits that have different meaning when read and written, such as the port pins. When written they set the latch and the output, when read they return the input. To configure a pin for input, you write a 1 to it. Suppose you have set `P1.0` to input and it is externally pulled low, that is it will be read as 0. Now if you want to set `P1.1` to input as well, you can do `SETB P1.1` and that will work fine. However if you read the value of `P1`, modify the value, then write it back, then it won't work:

```
MOV P1, #1 ; set P1.0 to input
MOV A, P1  ; reads 0
ORL A, #2
MOV P1, A  ; P1.0 no longer input
```

Note that `ORL P1, #2`, while it logically does the same, *works* because the processor has special support and knows to read the port latch instead of the pin input.

Another possibility you mentioned was the write triggering something. One such example is `SBUF`. Even if you write the same value there, it will trigger a transmission. However this isn't really relevant to your question, since it's not bit-addressable. In the context of standard 8051 I can't think of another SFR that exhibits similar behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but it is still not totally clear.

Indeed, writing same byte many times to ``UARTTX`` will trigger transmissions of these bytes, so, there is a clear answer, that writing same value is not same as keeping it untouched. But as you mentioned, it should probably not be applied to bit addressable SFRs.

As for your example, I can not agree with it. Setting ``P1.0`` direction, I can read it back. Same applies to output - I can read the value I've assigned previously to ``P1.0`` even if it is in OUT state.

Comment: Your 8051 clone might have some mode-setting support for P1. But standard 8051 works as I described: you set pin to 1, and externally you can pull that low in which case you will read it as 0.

Comment: It seems I've got your answer, but the code is not clear yet. When you write "to input" means set the direction of P1.0 to IN (using P1DIR SFR) or set it to high level (setting the P1 itself)? Are you allowed to set it if it is in IN mode?

In the opposite case it should be possible to read value from P1.0 in OUT mode to get the same value as you previously stored into it (the current level).

Comment: What's your exact chip type? Stock 8051 doesn't have P1DIR SFR at all. See [here](http://www.8052.com/images/sfr8051.gif). The legacy way to use a pin as input is to simply set it to 1 and let the external circuitry pull it low if it wants to send a 0.

Comment: Surprised to hear this! I was never using stock 8051. We use ZW0301 chip based on Inventra M8051 Warp.

So, if you are so good in 8051 arch, can you also tell me please if these commands are the only to be able alter an SFR? And am I right that I can divide them into commands setting the whole byte and those setting it by single bites (I mean internally inside the MCU).

As a byte: MOV, ADD, ADDC, SUBB, XCH, DEC, INC, POP, PUSH. By bits: ORL, ANL, XRL, SETB, CLR, CPL.

Are there others?

Comment: I'll explain in more details. We are doing an emulator of our chip. And commands in the group "As byte" are processed on the host, while to the h/w we will send only command with single MOV (we read from h/w with a MOV A, direct and send to host processor, then do the ADD or XCH, ... and then send back to the h/w a new value to do MOV direct, A.

For second (by bits) group we will have to implement each command in the h/w to set commands by bits using ORL, ANL, ...

Comment: In other words, can I substitute all commands from first group by equivalent commands dealing with A and Rx registers plus a final MOV direct, A.

And same with ORL direct, #immediate by MOV A, #immediate plus ORL direct, A ?